# Pipelining 1M requests on server using javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

What would be efficient JS code that pipelines 1M http requests, taking execution time, memory, simplicity and elegance into account. targeting web browser as client?

Comment: "targeting web browser as client?" what? "pipelines" from ... ? to ... ? What code have you written already? What doesnt work with that?

Comment: I have a web browser and http server. I am looking to [pipeline](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-8.1.2.2) trough single connection 1M requests from client  to server and then process every received request from server. Code that I have written so far is trivial, but is either slow and does not pipeline or it leaks memory and kills browser.

Comment: Do you really need all of them at the client? Couldn't you just aggregate results on the server and send them?

Comment: There is no need to separate aggregation.  It just makes error handling more complex. I beleive that is up to client to consume lot of requests. Additionally it enables server to process each request synchronously. Trivial C++ client makes 300k requests/s with minimal memory consumption. I am  would like to see how much JS can be squeezed. Is there simple design pattern for such task?